# Not able to get file object Using YUI IN Internext Explorer

Tags: file-upload, liferay-6, yui

I am trying to upload a file using YUI.
Below is my code that works fine in Firefox and Chrome.But not working in IE 8.

```
this.portlet_view_object.delegate('change', function(e) {
......
var fileField = Y.one('#newcase_file_'+context.imageCount);

        var file = fileField._node.files[0];

        if(!context.maxFileSize.call(context,file)){
            return;
        }
....
```

Here, the maxFileSize, is the method to which i pass the file object and perform operation related to fiel(e.g. fileSize, fileName).
In firefox and chrome, i am getting the file object by fileField._node.files[0];
But the same thing is not working in IE 8,and getting below error.
_node.files.0' is null or not an object

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This issue isn't related to YUI, just to IE.

`.files` holds multiple selected files, but IE8 does not support this methos and can only select one file. Therefore this property isn't recognized.

You can use this workaround:

```
if ('files' in fileField._node)
    var file = fileField._node.files[0];
else
    var file = fileField._node.value;
```

Or skip the whole `.files` completely if you want to, although I personally wouldn't recommend it.